# Ayuda error con los pods al ejecutar el simulador de xcode en MAC

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Al ejecutar mi aplicacion en xcode, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Toast_Swift.framework/Toast_Swift
  Referenced from: /Users/alberto/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/40EB2EEE-A6DC-4E26-BDDF-D7AE7A5A6BEE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A91A5FF4-4835-4EFA-BF79-5363E40057FB/Proyecto1.app/Proyecto1
  Reason: image not found
```

Cual puede ser el problema?? he actualizado los pods varias veces.
Tengo que añadir mas información para intentar solucionarlo?? Gracias

Asi esta la informacion general de la app

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Imagino que estás ejecutando el proyecto desde `.xcworkspace` y no desde el `.xcodeproj` ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente no se esta quejando de tu pods , se esta quejando de que en algun lado se esta haciendo referencia a un framework que ya no esta y que es el framework **Toast_Swift.framework** , asi que debes buscar dónde se esta haciendo referencia a este framework y eliminar esa referencia , después haz un clean y arranca de nuevo el proyecto.